# ASP.net Adding new Button to GridView give an error in jquery.dataTables.min.js

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I currently have a GridView and I'm trying to add a button. I'm able to add it but when I click on it I get this weird error on this line.

```
if(c.mData===a){var d=u(b,"sort")||u(b,"order"),e=u(b,"filter")||u(b,"search");
```

Error:

> Unhandled exception at line 91, column 426 in
>   http://localhost:23549/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js
>
> 0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'mData' is null or not
>   an object

I've done a bit of research and I can't find this issue anywhere else. Other users are getting the same error but none of them use ASP. I tried changing some properties on the button. I also tried adding it has a ButtonField instead but I still get the same error.

```
<div class="datatable">
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="jobGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderWidth="0px" GridLines="None" CssClass="table table-hover table-condensed font13" OnRowDataBound="jobGridView_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="site_id,id" OnRowCommand="OnOff">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="site_id" meta:resourcekey="siteField" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" meta:resourcekey="jobNameField" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="job_start_date" meta:resourcekey="jobStartField" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="job_end_date" meta:resourcekey="jobEndField" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="job_duration" meta:resourcekey="jobDurationField" DataFormatString="{0:HH:mm:ss.fff}" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="job_last_run_elapsed_time" meta:resourcekey="jobElapsedTimeField" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="return_code" meta:resourcekey="returnCodeField" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="return_description" meta:resourcekey="returnDescriptionField" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="status_code" meta:resourcekey="statusField" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="job_last_failure" meta:resourcekey="jobLastFailureField" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" Text="View" OnClientClick='<%# GetOpenTabJavascript(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id"), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "site_id"))%>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CommandName="OnOff" Text="Turn On/Off" ShowHeader="True" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

---

```
 protected void OnOff(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "OnOff")
            {
               //This part gets hit when debugging, error is after
            }

        }
```

If I remove the button everything works fine. (The LinkButton work)

I tried changing the type of event to RowEditing and RowUpdating. Same error.

Where should I start debugging to find out where the error comes from?
Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: I ran your code as it is as you posted here, I got no error even after pressing the button, I assume that there might be some other thing which is creating issue at your side not this part of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is being pretty straightforward in just letting you know `jquery.dataTables` is looking for an object named `mData` which is currently null and/or false.

Try giving your `<div class="datatable">` an ID to match what dataTables is looking for.

That is, `<div class="datatable" id="mData">`  I'm not 100% sure that will do it, but your solution will be definitely in the neighborhood.

I've used dataTables a lot and tended to run into lots of annoying errors like this that just took debugging and banging my head on the desk some before I figured it out.

Seems like otherwise (can't really tell without debugging myself) your code would be fine--you just need to explicitly tell dataTables what `mData` is.  If it's not on the `<div>`, maybe the button or `GridView`: honestly, too many variables for me to know for sure (unless you try some of these and have feedback! :))

Comment: My guess is it has to be set on the button because everything works if I remove the button.

Comment: You misunderstand what I meant... So the error is telling you that the property `mData` is null -- that means that it is not picking up whatever rows you are "selecting" or whatever it is you're trying to get the button to do to the data.  When you say it works if you remove the button: you can get it to do what you are trying to make the button do without the button?

Comment: The LinkButton  works and I didn't set mData to anything. This is why I'm confused

Comment: That's because your `lnkButton` is not doing `<%# Eval("id") %>`.  That button seems to use `DataBinder.Eval()` when grabbing the info?  Forgive me, long time since I messed with web forms style stuff so that syntax is a little wonky for me--maybe change the `CommandArgument` to `DataBinder.Eval("id")`?  Trust me, dataTables error messages (and js in general) tend to be red herrings and logic like the above statement basically doesn't apply, lol. ;)

Comment: I tried changing it to `CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id")%>' ` and `CommandArgument="DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 'id')"` both compile but I still get the same error :(

Comment: Booo.. (that was just a guess based on your above button, anyway).. Honestly that's most definitely the issue, I hope looking into it helps point you in the right direction.  Last thing: I also notice `OnClientClick` vs you're using `CommandArgument` -- again web forms not my strong point so.  Anyway, hope some of this helped in some way, lol.

Comment: You might be right I just need to find out how to get it working.

Comment: Thanks for your help